# Replicating through a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

```
replicatee :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
replicatee [] _ = []
replicatee xs 0 = []
replicatee (x:xs) n = x:replicatee (x:xs) (n-1): replicatee xs n
```

So this is my code for replicating a an element in a list n times, the compler keeps showing an error :

```
Couldnt match type 'a'with [a], I'm seriously confused, please help out.
```

Edit : what i want my function to do is this:
replicatee [1,2,3,4]  2

[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]

Comment: Well your first parameter is a *list*, but this does not make much sense, if you want to replicate a *single* element in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood your intention, but maybe you meant something like this:

```
replicatee :: a -> Int -> [a]
replicatee _ 0 = []
replicatee x n = x:replicatee x (n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replicatee :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
replicatee [] _ = []
replicatee xs 0 = []
replicatee (x:xs) n = x:replicatee (x:xs) (n-1): replicatee xs n
```

The problem is that `replicatee` returns a value of type `[a]`, but you try to add that to *another* list of type `[a]` using `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. From a type-checking perspective, you need to use `(++)`, not `(:)`:

```
replicatee xs'@(x:xs) n = x : (replicatee xs' (n-1) ++ replicatee xs n)
```

Whether it *does* what you intended is another matter. Based on your description, [Mikkel provides the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320143/1126841).